# JSONObject return null although it has values

Tags: java, android, json

those 4 simple lines of code:

```
JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
System.out.println("the line" + curr.getString("post"));
System.out.println("id: " + curr.optString("id"));
System.out.println("name: " + curr.optString("name"));
```

print the following output:

```
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: the line{"id":"0","name":"פטישי חציבה"}
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: id: 
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: name: 
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: the line{"id":"1","name":"מקדחות יהלום"}
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: id: 
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: name: 
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: the line{"id":"2","name":"מהדקי אדמה"}
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: id: 
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: name: 
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: the line{"id":"3","name":"מכונות פוליש"}
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: id: 
11-09 17:15:05.890 1580-1626/yuvallevy.powertoolsrental I/System.out: name:
```

Can someone help me understand how it is possible that if I print the whole line its clear that there is "id" for each line and also "name" and when I try to get only their values I get empty result?

that is the JSONArray:

```
[{"post":{"id":"0","name":"פטישי חציבה"}},{"post":{"id":"1","name":"מקדחות יהלום"}},{"post":{"id":"2","name":"מהדקי אדמה"}},{"post":{"id":"3","name":"מכונות פוליש"}}]
```

and that is one post:

```
{"id":"0","name":"פטישי חציבה"}
```

Comment: What is `post`? Is that a JSON string or an object? If it's an JSON object, you should probably be getting `id` and `name` from that.

Comment: If `post` is a JSONObject, I think you are going to want to do `"id: " + curr.optJSONObject("post").optString("id")`

Comment: I have just added the JSONArray - posts and JSONObject - post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to do this:

```
JSONObject curr = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
System.out.println("id: " + curr.optJSONObject("post").optString("id"));
System.out.println("name: " + curr.optJSONObject("post").optString("name"));
```